# How to generate oauth token using QuickBooks API and postman?

Tags: quickbooks, postman, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Can anyone help me on generating OAuth token using QuickBooks API and postman?
I am not able to create one using API.
and can u help me to get sample account data from an account QuickBooks API ?

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to download QBO's postman collection to debug an integration issue with my app. I use OAuth2.0 with Authorization Code as the grant type to authenticate a user from my app to QBO. This is what QBO offers now and its not upto the app developer's discretion.

You can download the QBO's Postman collection from [here](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/postman).
To access QBO's endpoint from Postman, you must first create and register an app entry with QBO. Doing so will give you ***ClientID*** and ***ClientSecret*** which are needed for authentication purposes. Also put `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback` as the ***RedirectURI*** for your app since you will be authenticating using Postman. If you have your website up and running, you can put the link to your website as the RedirectURI.

Once you open the collection in Postman, open the *Accounts* endpoint and switch to the *Authorization* tab

[image]

Click on *Get New Access Token*.
[image]

- ***CallbackURL*** is going to be what you put in the RedirectURL you registered your sample QBO app with.
- ***AuthURL*** and ***AccessTokenURL*** are taken from the QBO link I mentioned above. Paste these as is.
- ***ClientID*** and ***ClientSecret*** are the keys you get once you register your sample app with QBO.
- ***Scope*** can be used as is since you need to access the accounting endpoint.
- ***State*** can be any string that is returned intact after a successful authentication with QBO. It is something that your app can use for an extra check to ensure that you got a response from the right authorization server. Put any length string(do not leave it blank) in this case because we are only accessing the endpoints using Postman.
- ***ClientAuthentication*** is set to *Send client credentials in body* as instructed by QBO.

Once you click on *Request Token*, you will be redirected to QBO's login page inside Postman itself in a new popup window. Successful authentication will close the popup window and give you an *Access Token*. Clicking *Use Token* will set the token in the body at the time of Send Request.

Make sure you know your ***companyid*** and that you are targeting the right ***baseurl***. Notice that Im using ***minorversion*** 9 because thats what my app uses. You can choose to stick with 14.
[image]

Hitting *Send Request* should get you some accounts objects in the response.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in c# code?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the following blog which shows how to generate OAuth1 tokens using OAuthPlayground tool and use those tokens in POSTMAN to make any API calls.

https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2016/04/25/quick-start-to-quickbooks-online-rest-api-with-oauth1-0

You can try the entire QBO POSTMAN collection from the link below.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0400_tools/0012_postman?isExpand=false#/1500

Answer (score -1):

You can't generate OAuth tokens via Postman.

The whole point of OAuth is to give the end-user a UI-based process to click through and provide tokens.

Use the UI components Intuit provides to get your tokens.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000000_quickbooks_online_overview